# Continuity of canonical injection

Tags: general-topology

The task is to check if the canonical injection is continuous, given a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T} )$ and its subspace $(X', \mathcal{T}')$.
Canonical injection is defined as a mapping $i:X' \rightarrow X$ such that $i(x)=x$

I will use here a concrete example to demonstrate what I am unsure about with continuity.
$$X = \{a,b,c\} \quad \text{and} \quad X'=\{a,b\}$$
$$\mathcal{T} = \{ \varnothing, X, \{a,b\}, \{a\} \} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{T}'=\{ \varnothing, X', \{a\}\}$$

Mapping $i$ is continuous means here that every open set from $X$ is an image of an open set in $X'$. It is easy to confirm that all open sets from $X$ other that $X$ itself are an image of an open set. But what is $X$ image of? There is no element from $X'$ which is mapped into $c \in X$.

Formal definition of continuity in my textbook is:
$$Let \ \  \psi:(X,\mathcal{T}) \rightarrow (X', \mathcal{T'})$$
$$\psi \text{ is continuous} \iff (\forall T' \subset \mathcal{T'}) \implies \psi^{-1}(T') \subset \mathcal{T}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured it out while typing, I'll put up the answer here too.

Meaning of the inverse map in the definition plays the key role in understanding continuity and it's simple.

$$\psi^{-1}(T') = \{ x \in X \ | \ \psi(x) \in T' \}$$

In our example this means that $X$ "is the image of" $\{a,b\}$ because $$\{a,b\} = \{ x \in X' \ | \ i(x)=x\in X\}$$

This then implies that the map is indeed continuous.

Answer (score 1):

If $X' \subseteq X$ has the subspace topology wrt $\mathcal{T}$, the topology on $X$, then $\mathcal{T}' = \{O \cap X'\mid O \in \mathcal{T}\}$

If $i: X' \to X$ is the canonical injection, then

$$i^{-1}[O] = \{x \in X'\mid i(x) \in O\} = \{x \in X'\mid x\in O\} = O \cap X'$$

and so $i^{-1}[O]$ is open in $\mathcal{T}'$ if $O$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$, by the definition of the former topology.